# Not able to copy column names from erwin data modeler into a text file

Tags: erwin

I am new to Erwin data model tool. I want to copy the column names of a table into a text file, but I am not able to do by any means. Could you please help me to know how Can I achieve this.

Thanks
Priyaranjan